# Dynamic tsql error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The SQL below fails and gives me an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

The variable valu1 is a GUID that has "-" characters in it. I am using it as a varchar

```
    Declare @valu1 as varchar(1000)
Declare @valu2 as varchar(200)
    Declare @sqlStr as nvarchar(2000)

    Select @valu1 = GUID, 
           @valu2= RationaleText 
    From   dbo.tblll
    Where  column= 'New'

            SET @sqlStr =N'Insert Into dbo.table1                    
                            Select  newid()            as ChangeID, 
                                    GETDATE()          as DateModified,
                                    a.col1 as col1,  
                                    c.col2       as col2,   
                                    d.col3      as col3,
                                    ' + @valu1 + '  as valu1,
                                    ' + @valu2 + ' as valu2     
                            From     table1 a
                                     Inner Join table2 b On a.col1 = b.col7
                                     Left Join table2  c On b.col1 = c.col2 
                                     Left Join table3  d On b.col1 = d.col3
                            Order By a.col1 

           PRINT @sqlStr            
           Exec(@sqlStr)
```

When I print the above SQL - i get:

```
Insert Into dbo.table1                   
                                    Select  newid()            as ChangeID, 
                                            GETDATE()          as DateModified,
                                            a.col1 as col1,  
                                            c.col2       as col2,   
                                            d.col3       as  col3,
                                            DD989A2A-5B9C-4369-81E1-13C638F1C555  as valu1,
                                            New as valu2    
                                    From     table1 a
                                             Inner Join table2 b On a.col1 = b.col7
                                             Left Join table2  c On b.col1 = c.col2 
                                             Left Join table3  d On b.col1 = d.col3
                                    Order By a.col1
```

Comment: Show us what the `PRINT @sqlStr` is showing you.  That's why it's in there.

Comment: just modified the question..something that i am missing in the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @sqlStr =N'Insert Into dbo.table1                    
                        Select  newid()            as ChangeID, 
                                GETDATE()          as DateModified,
                                a.col1 as col1,  
                                c.col2       as col2,   
                                d.col3      as col3,
                                ''' + @valu1 + '''  as valu1,
                                ''' + @valu2 + ''' as valu2     
                        From     table1 a
```

Notice the extra quotes. Also note that this is incredibly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You should investigate using [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead of concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Please try putting more quotes around the variables:

```
''' + @valu1 + '''  as valu1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `SET @sqlStr` the end of the string is missing a closing single quotation mark at the end. There should be a `'` after `Order By a.col1`.

I tried this on <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1aaed/1)</kbd> and it worked:

```
Declare @valu1 as varchar(1000)
Declare @valu2 as varchar(200)
Declare @sqlStr as nvarchar(2000)

Select @valu1 = GUID, 
       @valu2= RationaleText 
From   dbo.tblll
Where  column= 'New'

SET @sqlStr =N'Insert Into dbo.table1                    
                Select  newid()            as ChangeID, 
                        GETDATE()          as DateModified,
                        a.col1 as col1,  
                        c.col2       as col2,   
                        d.col3      as col3,
                        ' + @valu1 + '  as valu1,
                        ' + @valu2 + ' as valu2     
                From     table1 a
                         Inner Join table2 b On a.col1 = b.col7
                         Left Join table2  c On b.col1 = c.col2 
                         Left Join table3  d On b.col1 = d.col3
                Order By a.col1'

PRINT @sqlStr            
Exec(@sqlStr)
```

You may also need to enclose @valu1 and @valu2 in single quotation marks since they are strings. You will need to use double-single quotation marks to escape them in the string.

```
''' + @valu1 + '''  as valu1,
''' + @valu2 + ''' as valu2
```